# Passing Radio Value to controller

Tags: c#, html

I have a radio button option on a question in a html formular. This is what the html looks like. Im using MDboostsrap for design.

```
<h4>Whats the type?</h4>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
  <input value="verlust" type="radio" class="custom-control-input AnzeigeRadio" id="VerlustanzeigeRadio" name="Anzeige_typ" checked>
  <label value="diebsthal" class="custom-control-label" for="VerlustanzeigeRadio">Verlustanzeige</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
  <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input AnzeigeRadio" id="DiebstahlanzeigeRadio" name="Anzeige_typ">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="DiebstahlanzeigeRadio">Diebstahlanzeige</label>
</div>
```

This is the current Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult Create( string Anzeige_typ)
{
   //Now I just have an "On" Value on the Anzeige_Typ string
}
```

I would for example like if the "Anzeige_Typ" would pass the ID from the selected radiobutton to the controller. With the current "On" i cant even tell which one was selected.

Comment: How are you calling Create function? Where are you passing Anzeige_typ?

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Meldungs", FormMethod.Post))
{}

Comment: Edit your question and include that and more of the view/HTML code. It's hard to see the problem like this. If possible, copy whole HTML form code.

Comment: Your second radio  button does not have `value=""`

Comment: what? That value I just added before to try something out. I initially had no value set

Comment: Any reason you're not using the `Html.RadioButtonFor()` with a model?

Comment: Not familiar with it at all. Never really used those.

Comment: Your SECOND radio button add `value="iforgotthis"` and test that.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss ohhh right that worked thats man